# Cant find layout folder with android project

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to integrate admob services using this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#place_an_adview_in_your_main_activity_layout), but i'm getting stuck on part `Place an AdView in your main activity layout`as it says to go to `/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml`, However, I dont have any layout folder, not even the main folder actually.

[image]

I'm using Ionic 2 framework with sidebar template in case this helps.

Got any ideas guys? Would grantly appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Just create one layout folder inside res folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create this AdView programmatically or you need to use AdView plugin for Ionic. You are developing cross-platform app with Ionic.

Please check this that I found for you: 
https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/06/using-admob-ionicframework/

And also here is the AdMob plugin for Ionic. AdView is the part of the AdMob for Android. 
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob

Comment: So I dont have to modify build.gradle, string.xml etc, as said on the official tutorial ? Just following the tuto you sent will make it works properly?

Comment: Yes. You are developing cordova based application with Ionic. Let cordova handle it. If it cannot handle and you got "class not found" kind error for AdMob open build.gradle and add AdMob library but first let cordova plugin system try. Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your sidebar layout to "Project" as shown in this image:

[image]